# NaN error in distance from your location calculator

Tags: javascript, html, coordinates, distance, nan

I need a tool to measure distance beetween a fixed point and my location. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula/27943#27943) code to calculate the distance and created the part that takes coordinates from browser.
Get distance () returns NaN. What's wrong?

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
  };
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

  function success(pos) {
    var lat1 = pos.coords.latitude;
    var lon1 = pos.coords.longitude;
    var lat2 = 50; //Sample target latitude
    var lon2 = 20; //Sample target longitude
  }

  function error(err) {
    document.getElementById('demo').textContent = "Error.";
  }

  //haversine formula

  function getDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
    var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
    var a =
      Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
      Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
      Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    return d;
  }

  function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI / 180)
  }

  function final(getDistance, success, lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, pos) {
    document.getElementById('demo').textContent = "Distance: " + getDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, success);
  }
  final(getDistance);
</script>
```

Comment: You're only calling `final(getDistance);` with a single parameters, so all the rest is undefined (`success`, `lat1`, `lat2`, ...). And your `success` function does nothing at all. It declares variables that cannot be accessible from outside, and does nothing with them, does not return anything

Comment: If I put other parameters there,  the error occurs: Uncaught ReferenceError: lat1 is not defined

Comment: Because it is undefined as well. You never declare a `lat1` variable that is accessible outside of the `success` function. Also note that [`getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API/Using_the_Geolocation_API#getting_the_current_position). So your `final` function is called before the `success` function had a chance to be executed

Comment: I think you should read this before anything else...: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- [`getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API/Using_the_Geolocation_API#getting_the_current_position) is asynchronous. By the time you call `final`, `success` has not yet been executed.
- Your `success` function declares local variables. They cannot be used outside of it
- You call `final` with a single parameter, not providing it `lat1`, `lat2`...

Here is a [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/blex41/pen/bGwQQga?editors=1010) *(StackSnippets don't allow using the location)*.

And a fixed version of the code:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

function success(pos) {
  var lat1 = pos.coords.latitude;
  var lon1 = pos.coords.longitude;
  var lat2 = 50; //Sample target latitude
  var lon2 = 20; //Sample target longitude

  final(getDistance, lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2); // <-- call it from here
}

function error(err) {
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = "Error.";
}

//haversine formula

function getDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
  var a =
    Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) *
      Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
      Math.sin(dLon / 2) *
      Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
}

function final(getDistance, lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = "Distance: " + getDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
}
```